# How do I use Automapper Projections in a Generic Repository to avoid circular references?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, repository-pattern, circular-reference

I'm using a generic repository in my MVC application and I also use automapper for mapping between the viewmodel.  The reason I need this is to avoid circular references from my models and also to leverage data annotations etc.  I have recenlt swithced to a `Generic Repository` pattern and `unit of work` but I no longer seem to be able to use Automapper's `.ProjectTo`.

Here is my code, this is called by a KendoUI MVC Grid, it returns a list of data (which has a relationship and thus circular references).

```
public ActionResult GetItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var item = unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Get();
    var result = item.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result);
}
```

To get around the circular reference I use a viewmodel, this also allows me to have additional control over my data.  What I find is that it won't let me use project to.

```
public ActionResult GetItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var item = unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Get().ProjectTo<ItemViewModel>;
    var result = item.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Intellisense returns an error of:

> Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable

What is going wrong and is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing parenthesis off the end of the `ProjectTo<>()` call:

```
var item = unitOfWork.ItemRepository.Get().ProjectTo<ItemViewModel>();
```